# What is a good program for matrix groups computations?

Tags: finite-groups, computer-algebra

I need a computer program, to help me with some very basic group computations.
Specifically, I want to know if some group generated by a few small matrices over a finite field is solvable.
Is there a free program or on-line tool which can do this?

Comment: While Magma is not free, if your calculations are small enough, then you can use their free online calculator: http://magma.maths.usyd.edu.au/calc/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, [GAP](http://www.gap-system.org/). It has an extensive functionality for computing with matrix groups over finite fields.